# Typehints for Sized Iterable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function that uses the `len` function on one of it's parameters and iterates over the parameter. Now I can choose whether to annotate the type with `Iterable` or with `Sized`, but both gives errors in `mypy`.

```
from typing import Sized, Iterable


def foo(some_thing: Iterable):
    print(len(some_thing))
    for part in some_thing:
        print(part)
```

Gives

```
error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Iterable[Any]"; expected "Sized"
```

While

```
def foo(some_thing: Sized):
...
```

Gives

```
error: Iterable expected
error: "Sized" has no attribute "__iter__"
```

Since there is no `Intersection` as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) I need to have some kind of mixed class.

```
from abc import ABCMeta
from typing import Sized, Iterable


class SizedIterable(Sized, Iterable[str], metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass


def foo(some_thing: SizedIterable):
    print(len(some_thing))
    for part in some_thing:
        print(part)


foo(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

This gives an error when using `foo` with a `list`.

```
error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "List[str]"; expected "SizedIterable"
```

This is not too surprising since:

```
>>> SizedIterable.__subclasscheck__(list)
False
```

So I defined a `__subclasshook__` (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__)).

```
class SizedIterable(Sized, Iterable[str], metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
        return Sized.__subclasscheck__(subclass) and Iterable.__subclasscheck__(subclass)
```

Then the subclass check works:

```
>>> SizedIterable.__subclasscheck__(list)
True
```

But `mypy` still complains about my `list`.

```
error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "List[str]"; expected "SizedIterable"
```

How can I use type hints when using both the `len` function and iterate over my parameter? I think casting `foo(cast(SizedIterable, ['a', 'b', 'c']))` is not a good solution.

Answer (score 66):

Starting from Python3.6 there's a new type called `Collection`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection).

Comment: Is `Collection` preferable over `Iterator` when the `len()` function is used?

Comment: An `Iterator` doesn't have size. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes

Comment: PyCharm seems to still warn when it is an ItemView (dict.items())

Comment: `Value of type "Collection[Any]" is not indexable`... is there a type for something I can iterate over, can call len() on, and getitem by index?!

Comment: @JamesOwers: That's a Sequence.

Comment: @ijoseph I think you mean `from typing import Sequence` rather than `from typing from Sequence` (I'm being pedantic, I know, but just in case anyone gets confused).

Comment: Make sure you use `from typing import Sequence` for type hints, not `from collections.abc import Sequence`  (thanks typo correction, @DouglasWinship)

Answer (score 20):

You should go with `Sequence` from [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) if you plan to use only list or tuple and access its elements by index, like `x[0]`. `Sequence` is both `Sized` and `Iterable`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

Comment: This will not work for regular and frozen sets. They do not implement `__getitem__` as expected of sequences.

Comment: Good point. It only works with an indexable (implementing `__getitem__`), like a list or a tuple. In a more general case, use `Collection`, as suggested by Avision.

Comment: Sequences are `Iterable` as a consequence of needing the `__getitem__` method, not simply being `Iterable`.

Answer (score 15):

In the future `Protocol`s will be introduced. They are already available through [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/typing-extensions/3.6.2.1). See also [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/). Using `Protocol` the code above would be:

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol


class SizedIterable(Protocol):

    def __len__(self):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        pass


def foo(some_thing: SizedIterable):
    print(len(some_thing))
    for part in some_thing:
        print(part)


foo(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

`mypy` takes that code without complaining. But PyCharm is saying

> Expected type 'SizedIterable', got 'List[str]'

about the last line.

Comment: Protocol definitions have already [been introduced](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#typing) in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a class like this?

```py
class MyArray:
  _array: list

  def as_tuple(self):
    return tuple(self._array)

  def as_list(self):
    return self._array
    
    # More Feature to implement
```