# Python what is the correct typing for any iterable that also exposes len()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

I have a function that works for any iterable that can return its length.
So it works for list, dict, and also dict.tems(), which is `ItemsView`.

What is the correct typing I should use for it?

EDIT:
Here is an example function:

```
def print_iter(some_iterable: xxx):
    for idx, val in enumerate(some_iterable):
        print(val, idx, len(some_iterable))
```

I'm not sure what typing to use instead of the `xxx`

Comment: Note that the (currently) highest-voted answer on the proposed duplicate isn't what you want; see the [answer using `Protocol`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49434182/1126841), or my answer below.

Comment: @che Because Collection must also have `__contains__`? / You could leave that comment on that answer instead of here.

Comment: Actually, I retract my comment; I misremembered what `Collection` was for. But `__contains__` may indeed be more specific than you need.

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the [`typing_extensions`](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions) module and define a new `Protocol` subclass.

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol


class SupportsLen(Protocol):
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 0  # Exact value unimportant; this is for the type checker only.


def print_iter(some_iterable: SupportsLen):
    for idx, val in enumerate(some_iterable):
        print(val, idx, len(some_iterable))
```

(For completeness, `SupportsLen` should probably also define whatever you need for it to actually *be* iterable.)

Comment: Can we Inherit from `typing.Iterable` and add our additional functions, i.e. `__len__`

Comment: I am not sure. I don't know the details of what makes a `Protocol` different from an ordinary abstract base class that makes it necessary to provide.

Comment: Ok,  I will look into it myself.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal `Protocol` uses "structural subtyping", so you don't need to declare that every class "implements" the relevant type, it just needs to have the relevant members declared.  for some reason the original type hints pep 484 went with nominal subtyping which is closer to C++/Java but seems less compatible with Python's duck typing

Comment: @SamMason can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal this is a very big topic, I don't think a few comments here will help much...  the wikipedia pages ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system)) contain overviews and both reference [TAPL](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) which I'd recommend if you're interested in these sorts of things.  the original [c2 wiki](http://wiki.c2.com/?NominativeAndStructuralTyping) also has a nice summary