# Type Hint for finite iterable

Tags: python, iterable, type-hinting

My function `foo` accepts an argument `things` which is turned into a list internally.

```
def foo(things):
    things = list(things)
    # more code
```

The `list` constructor accepts any iterable.

However, annotating `things` with `typing.Iterable` does not give the user a clue that the iterable must be finite, not something like `itertools.count()`.

What's the correct type hint to use in this case?

Comment: That's not something you can express in a type hint. (How would such a hint even be checked? mypy can't solve the halting problem to figure out whether a generator is finite.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm more concerned about good documentation than static type checking. How would you let the user know what `things` can be? In the docstring?

Comment: I think the answer may be given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427944/typehints-for-sized-iterable-in-python . There is also mention of the 'new type called Collection' (as given in the answer to your question from @Giorgos)

Comment: @actual_panda: Documentation goes in the documentation. Type hints are not intended to specify all possible restrictions on allowed argument values; "finite iterable", "positive integer", "uppercase string", etc. are all not hintable.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I get your point but I don't think your examples are good. I can write an `UnsignedInteger` class or an `UppercaseString` class and hint it, but I can't write `FiniteIterable`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not aware of any possible way to achieve this in Python as you cannot provide such constraints in type hints.

---

However, probably the [`Collection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection) type might be useful in your context as a workaround:

> `class collections.abc.Collection`
>
> ABC for sized iterable container classes.

This requires objects to have a `__len__`, which is a more strict requirement than being finite. For example, finite generators don't count as `Collection`.