# Combination of types with python typing

Tags: python, types

When using Python type annotations, is it possible specify that a variable has multiple types?  I am trying to do something like this:

```
from typing import Iterable

class Base:
    pass

class D1(Base):
    pass

class D2(Base):
    pass


def foo(a: Iterable[D1],
        b: Iterable[D2]) -> None:
    sizes = [ (d, l) for d in (a,b) if (l := len(d))]

    # Not the actual use case, but a and b need to be Iterable, not just Sized
    for lst, size in sizes:
        for elem in lst:
            print(f"Element {elem} in list of size {size}")
```

`mypy` does not like this:

```
sample.py:15: error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Iterable[Base]"; expected "Sized"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I think I am looking for something like `Union` but which specifies both, not either.  Changing the type of `a` to `Iterable[D1] & Sized` should work if `&` worked like the obvious analogue of `|`, but it does not.

It seems that I might need to define a `SizedIterable` type, but I'm failing on that.  The best I've done is

```
D = TypeVar('D')
class SizedIterable(Generic[D], Sized, Iterable[D]):
    pass

def foo(a: SizedIterable[D1],
        b: SizedIterable[D2]) -> None:
    the_list: List[SizedIterable[Base]] = [a,b]
    sizes: List[Tuple[SizedIterable[Base], int]] = [ (d, l) for d in the_list if (l := len(d))]
```

which fails:

```
sample.py:18: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "SizedIterable[D1]"; expected "SizedIterable[Base]"
sample.py:18: error: List item 1 has incompatible type "SizedIterable[D2]"; expected "SizedIterable[Base]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Just putting `(a,b)` in the comprehension also fails, as mypy only infers `object` as the type of the iterable.

Is there a way to get the types to work here?  I'm about ready to get rid of all the type annotations, as at least then `mypy` would be happy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427944/typehints-for-sized-iterable-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `Sequence` type:

```
from typing import Sequence

...

def foo(a: Sequence[D1],
        b: Sequence[D2]) -> None:
    sizes = [ (d, l) for d in (a,b) if (l := len(d))]

    # Not the actual use case, but a and b need to be Iterable, not just Sized
    for lst, size in sizes:
        for elem in lst:
            print(f"Element {elem} in list of size {size}")
```